Automatic creation of records in database tables
I have an Express application, PostgreSQL is used as a database, and Sequelize is used as an ORM.
I connect to the database as follows:
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript";
import "dotenv/config";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    dialect: "postgres",
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    models: [__dirname + "/models/**"]
});

And this is how I describe my models:
import { Table, Column, Model, DataType, ForeignKey, HasMany } from 'sequelize-typescript';

import Message from './Message';

@Table({
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "message_types"
})
class MessageType extends Model {
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
    })
    type: string;

    @HasMany(() => Message, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
    messages: Message[];
}

export default MessageType;

Question: how can I do to automatically fill the database table with standard values initially? for example, fill the message_types table with the values: Default, Deleted, System, Voice, Video.
Now it works for me as follows: when the application is started, the initMessageTypes method of the MessageTypeService service is called:
import { Op } from "sequelize";

import MessageType from "../../db/models/messenger/MessageType";
import { MessageTypes } from "types/messenger";

const initialTypes: string[] = [
    MessageTypes.Default,
    MessageTypes.Deleted,
    MessageTypes.System,
    MessageTypes.Voice,
    MessageTypes.Video
];

class MessageTypeService {
    async initMessageTypes() {
        initialTypes.forEach(async (type) => {
            const existedType = await MessageType.findOne({
                where: {
                    type
                }
            });

            if (!existedType) {
                await MessageType.create({
                    type
                });
            }
        });

        return await MessageType.destroy({
            where: {
                type: {
                    [Op.notIn]: initialTypes
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

export default new MessageTypeService();


Usually such things are done by using migrations and seeders

And if change a list later in code then you need to create a new migration/seeder to reflect these changes
